# Tag name for "speech used by/understood by young children"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-request

I think it would be useful to have a tag for speech that is meant to be used when talking to young children.  For example, "[How to tell a child that he did something wrong](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70347)" could benefit from such a tag.

This tag would be similar to the dialect tags, in that it describes a specialized form of English that is used by an easily defined category of people.  In this case, the category is children between 3 and 7 years of age.  They have limited vocabularies.  Does anyone have suggestions for a good name for this new tag?

[baby-talk](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-talk) is obviously inappropriate.  Baby-talk is often inarticulate, and is not meant to be a strict subset of English proper.

Comment: I'd want to see more of such questions before supporting a new tag. As a footnote, if I was trying to encourage my child for doing something right (or discourage them from doing something wrong), I wouldn't want to limit my vocabulary. [Neither would StoneyB](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171). I think that's why many of us bristle at "baby talk."

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a somewhat awkward possibility: [childrens-dialect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childrens-dialect). Unfortunately, it's impossible to use apostrophes in tags, so it looks stupid.

Contemplating that further, [talking-to-children](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking-to-children) is not amazingly terrible, and is within the maximum tag length. Or a punchier version: [kid-talk](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kid-talk), which would need usage guidance and may be too idiomatic for learners that are not aware that informal English refers to children as kids (or are not thinking about that).

Comment: "it's impossible to use apostrophes in tags" ... as my late Mother was wont to say: _Pour the hell quoi?_